# Desktop shortcut-key

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys

In Windows you can visualize the desktop with the combination <kbd>Windows-key</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>.

Is there something like this in Ubuntu (16.04)? Can I implement it in some way?

Comment: *System Parameter* -> *Keyboard* -> *Shortcuts* -> *Navigation* -> **Hide all normal window**; by defaut, this shortcut is **Ctrl** + **Super** + **D** (**Super** is the "Windows logo" key)

Comment: @damadam: Would you mind to write that as an answer please? :-)